# Invalid directory issue in azure website

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, azure

I have a web app which calls an internal API. This web verifier is working fine on my other instance which works on plesk. Recently I installed an instance of same verifier on azure. Everything works fine, the api, the proxy.. everything is working fine, but I get just 1 error regarding invalid path. I tried to search for answers but couldn't find anything. Can anyone guide please?[image: Error Screenshot]

Here's my web.config code:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="EmailCheckDemo.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="EmailValidation.asmx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\Temp;" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <healthMonitoring>
      <rules>
        <remove name="Failure Audits Default" />
      </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
    <httpHandlers>
            <add path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" validate="false" />
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" name="UrlRoutingModule" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="3276899" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Cobisi.EmailVerify, Version=4.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B863A804C9B2BDB0" />
        <add assembly="Cobisi.EmailVerify.Design, Version=4.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B863A804C9B2BDB0" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="BPSocks" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/EmailVerifier.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
        <add tagPrefix="juice" namespace="Juice" assembly="JuiceUI" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <location path="ChartImage.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="ChartImg.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>


</configuration>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net:Invalid temp directory in chart handler configuration \[c:\TempImageFiles\‌\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660606/asp-netinvalid-temp-directory-in-chart-handler-configuration-c-tempimagefiles)

Comment: I tried all the solutions there. No success. Can you please help?